# put 2 buttons on a stackpanel, but the position result is quit strange

Tags: c#, xml, uwp

I want to get is put 2 bottuns on a stackpanel

[image]

so my code is

```
<StackPanel x:Name="selectNumbersBottomStackPanel_"  BorderBrush="Gray"   BorderThickness="1" Height="524" Width="1045">
    
    <Button Content="111" Width="90" Height="26" Margin="122,48,0,0">
    </Button>
    <Button Content="222" Width="90" Height="26" Margin="222,48,0,0">
    </Button>

</StackPanel>
```

but the actual display does not act as I expect.

[image]

and I found I have to change code as below

```
<StackPanel x:Name="selectNumbersBottomStackPanel_"  BorderBrush="Gray"   BorderThickness="1" Height="524" Width="1045">
     <Button Content="111" Width="90" Height="26" Margin="122,48,0,0">
     </Button>
     <Button Content="222" Width="90" Height="26" Margin="222,-26,0,0"><!--I have to change 48 to -26 ---->
     </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Your comment welcome

Comment: The problem is the default  Orientation of StackPanel is `Vertical` that means 222 button will place below 111 button. So the 222's margin-top(48) will base on the 111.

Comment: I'm checking `FutureAccessList` issue, unfortunately you have deleted. the problem is you have not place 1.txt file in to output folder. if you want I will share my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `Orientation="Horizontal"` for your StackPanel and lower your left margin of the second button. The default StackPanel orientation is Vertical so you get that strange view (which you tried to fix with negative margin).

```
<StackPanel x:Name="selectNumbersBottomStackPanel_"  BorderBrush="Gray"   BorderThickness="1" Height="524" Width="1045" Orientation="Horizontal">
     <Button Content="111" Width="90" Height="26" Margin="122,48,0,0"/>
     <Button Content="222" Width="90" Height="26" Margin="10,48,0,0"/>
</StackPanel>
```